# Flutter Doctor is not detecting Visual Studio Code on my PC

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I just installed flutter on my Windows 10 system. I had Visual Studio Code v1.26.1 installed previously on my system. But whenever I run flutter doctor from the Git Bash, I notice VS Code is not detected by the Flutter Doc. So whenever I type the command in Git bash:

```
    $ flutter doctor
```

The outputs that I get is:

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.6.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228], locale en-US)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    [!] Connected devices
        ! No devices available

    ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

But if Flutter detects VS Code, the desired outputs that I have observed in other systems in online Flutter Installation Guidelines, is: 
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.6.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228], locale en-US)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version <--the installed version-->)
    [!] Connected devices
        ! No devices available

    ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I know the devices issue is showing as I haven't connected any android device neither running any emulator. But cannot figure out why VS Code is not being detected by flutter doc. I am a newbie to flutter so I am not sure either if it's okay if VS Code isn't shown here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will happen if:

- You have installed VS Code in a non-default location
- You have installed the newer "User Level" installation of VS Code

The first one is expected - we don't go looking for VS Code, we only check the default install locations.

The second one has been fixed in latest Flutter code (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/21070) but is likely not in the version you have yet. In this case, it'll start appearing in a future update.

> I am not sure either if it's okay if VS Code isn't shown here

It's absolutely okay - all this does is a basic check for VS Code and the extension as a hint to those that may use VS Code and not realise there's a VS Code extension. Not showing in Doctor will have no impact on the use of VS Code or the extension at all.

Comment: In my PC, VS Code is installed in the directory (C:\Users\Rahit_PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code) which is stated as the expected installation directory for VS Code in the VS Code documentation by Microsoft. And yes I have the newer User Level VS Code. Will be waiting for the update. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Is there a way to have Flutter Doctor check for VS Code Insiders edition? This is the only version of VS Code I use on my machines. To me, this is not a non-default location.

Comment: It should already. If it's not detecting it in the default location, please raise an issue in flutter/flutter and cc me (DanTup). Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

**I got Solution for "Flutter Not detecting the local Visual Studio" after I struggled for two days**

usually we install Visual Studion Enterprise Edition. But it is the problem. We have to go for Visual Studion Community Edition.
its link is https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16

while installing through Visual Studio 2019 installer, in the workload options, carefully select the flutter doctor asked MSVL and Windows C++ versions.

install the Visual Studio IDE which comes along with the above installation (even though you don't use that IDE) and keep it aside.

finally restart your computer after Visual Studio IDE installation.

now flutter doctor will detect your visual studion.

Comment: Visual Studio and VS Code are completely different things. This question is about VS Code.